# Blade template not showing section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have these three blade templates

In my controller I'm calling dashboard view like this:

```
View::make('layouts.dashboard');
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<?= stylesheet_link_tag() ?>
<?= javascript_include_tag() ?>

<html>
<body class="fixed">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="leftside">
            @yield('leftside', 'left-side content')
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            @yield('rightside', 'right-side content')       
        </div>   
    </div>

</body>
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('leftside')
    @yield('sidebar', 'sidebar content')
@stop
```

**sidebar.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('sidebar')
  aaa
@stop
```

The dasbhoard blade shows properly in master blade, but **sidebar blade doesn't want to show**. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thank your very much for any help :)

Comment: Which view are you calling to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use yield() on a blade template that is not called.

Basically what you can do is make your **master.blade.php** into this

```
<html>
<body class="fixed">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="leftside">
            @include('sidebar') {{-- This is sidebar.blade.php --}}
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            @include('dashboard') {{-- This is dashboard.blade.php --}}      
        </div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, assuming that your are calling the **dashboard.blade.php** template, with both blade templates included. You can use the sections on either master.blade, or sidebar.blade inside dashboard.blade

```
@extends('layouts.master')

{{-- You can define now the sections available on master.blade and dashbard.blade --}}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out what was wrong :)

I called View::make('layouts.dashboard') instead of **View::make('layouts.sidebar')**;